# Using Facebook authentication system without installing the app

Tags: facebook, accounts

Is there a way to add Facebook account to `Android Accounts` in order to ease login with apps, without installing the memory consuming and invasive Facebook app ?

Comment: I don't have the Facebook app on my Android phone, but I do have the Facebook "Messenger" app installed (it's tiny) and that logs in normally. Does that do what you want?

[Originally posted incorrectly as an Answer. (Corrected thanks to advice from Firelord)]